# Can I use w.document.getElementById('password')

Tags: javascript, get

I would like to open up a log-in page in another tab and have it insert text in the value of the password and name input boxes.  I am somewhat of a beginner.

This is what I have, but it never changes the value of the >input<

```
var w=window.open("link");
var pass = 'yourpassword'
setTimeout(function(){w.document.getElementById('pin').value = pass},3000);
```

in the other page there is:

```
<input name="pin" type="password" maxlength="20" id="pin" onfocus="this.select()" style="width:150px;">
```

Comment: I usually wait for the onload event like: w.onload = function() { ...; } instead of a setTimeout. Also the link should be on the same domain that your actual page.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `tag` and append it as string into another window something like this.

```
var w=window.open("suamn.html");
var pass = 'yourpassword';
var myTag = '<input name="pin" type="password" value="'+pass+'" maxlength="20" id="pin" onfocus="this.select()" style="width:150px;">';
w.document.write(myTag);
```

Comment: You do understand that the OP is trying to access the other window's element? In that case, `w.document` is needed, otherwise it's referring to the current document

Comment: @Ian, thanks for the pointed out, please have a look updated answer.